# problems moving site

Tags: session, server-setup, memcache

I moved a magento(1.5.1) site to a new server.
In `local.xml` I replaced
 `<session_save><![CDATA[memcache]]></session_save>` with 
`<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>` 
the login  (front and admin admin throws this message **"Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page."** 
Also when I add a product to the cart it does not get added is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i got the answer i needed to update `web/cookie/cookie_domain` value to my new URL in the `core_config_data` table

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like permissions issue and your server cannot write the session files. Can you double check permissions for Var Magento docs suggest it should be 700

Comment: i checked it has permission 777

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: Inside var do you have a session folder?

Comment: yes also has 777

Comment: Mm strange is there a reason you have changed to files from memcache

Comment: i dont fave memcache on this server

Comment: Strange Have any app/code/core files been edited. The issue could be due to a session being set elsewhere as explained here https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/magento/session-error-in-magento

Comment: my session files are being created